# JavaScript convert Array of 4 bytes into a float value from modbusTCP read

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to convert a array of 4 bytes to a float value. Here is the thing:

I get an answer from my request via ModbusTCP, this looks something like this:

```
{ "data": [ 16610, 40202 ], "buffer": { "type": "Buffer", "data": [ 64, 226, 157, 10 ] } }
```

This string is converted into a json-object, parsed and accessed with

```
var ModbusArray = JSON.parse(msg.payload);
var dataArray = ModbusArray.buffer.data;
```

(the msg.payload comes from node red)

Until here it works find. The Array represents a floating value. In this case it should be a value of around 7.0.

So, here is my Question: how can I get a float from this dataArray?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could adapt the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40970862/1447675) of [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)  and use [`DataView#setUint8`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setUint8) for the given bytes.

```js
var data =  [64, 226, 157, 10];

// Create a buffer
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
// Create a data view of it
var view = new DataView(buf);

// set bytes
data.forEach(function (b, i) {
    view.setUint8(i, b);
});

// Read the bits as a float; note that by doing this, we're implicitly
// converting it from a 32-bit float into JavaScript's native 64-bit double
var num = view.getFloat32(0);
// Done
console.log(num);
```

Comment: Be warned: getFloat32() does not give the expected 6~9 significant digits of a 32-bit floating point number... instead it is lazy and doesn't round at all, giving you the 17 digits of a double. So make sure you round off at 6 or 7 sigdigs manually after using getFloat32() or you may get extra digits due to getFloat32() incorrectly equivating the precision of a single's 23-bit mantissa onto a double's 52-bit mantissa.

Answer (score 10):

For decoding a float coded in Big Endian (ABCD) with Node.js:

```
Buffer.from([ 64, 226, 157, 10 ]).readFloatBE(0)
```

Comment: i ended up using https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-file

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy data in a loop :

```
var data =  [64, 226, 157, 10];

// Create a buffer
var buf = new Uint8Array(data).buffer
// Create a data view of it
var view = new DataView(buf);

var num = view.getFloat32(0);
// Done
console.log(num);
```