# Hex String to INT32 - Little Endian (DCBA Format) Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, decode

Implementing something based on a pathetic documentation without no info nothing.

The example is just this

```
(7F02AAF7)H => (F7AA027F)H = -139853185
```

Let's say even if I convert `7F02AAF7` to `F7AA027F`, then still the output via
`'parseInt('F7AA027F', 16)'` is different from what I am expecting.

I did some google search and found this website http://www.scadacore.com/field-tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/

Here when you input `7F02AAF7` then it is processed to wanted number under `INT32 - Little Endian (DCBA)` system. I tried this search term but no luck. 
Can you please tell me what exactly am I supposed to do here and is there any node.js library which can help me with this.

Comment: *"is different from what I am expecting"* - What are you expecting and why?

Comment: I am expecting decimal value `-139853185`? Because that's what people generally use for hex to decimal in js. @ArtjomB.

Comment: I have tried endian swapping as well. That didn't work either :l

Comment: The `parseInt()` function is not going to recognize that leading `F` as meaning that the number is negative. Without a leading "-" it will produce a positive value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could adapt the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40970862/1447675) of [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)  and use [`DataView#setUint8`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setUint8) for the given bytes with [`DataView#getInt32`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getInt32) and an indicator for littleEndian.

```js
var data = '7F02AAF7'.match(/../g);

// Create a buffer
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
// Create a data view of it
var view = new DataView(buf);

// set bytes
data.forEach(function (b, i) {
    view.setUint8(i, parseInt(b, 16));
});

// get an int32 with little endian
var num = view.getInt32(0, 1);
console.log(num);
```

Comment: Damn... Works everywhere else properly

Comment: What About INT32 - Big Endian (ABCD) ?

Answer (score 4):

Node can do that pretty easily using [buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html):

```
Buffer.from('7F02AAF7', 'hex').readInt32LE()
```

Comment: Thank you Robert for this solution.

Comment: What if you don't know the length of the hex string?

Comment: @Robin-Hoodie for an INT32, which is what the question was about, the length is fixed. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a variable which stores a hex string for which I don't know the length up front. I could check the length manually and then call `readInt32LE|readInt16LE|...` but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Your answer does answer the question though, so feel free to ignore

Comment: @Robin-Hoodie I think checking the length and picking the right method is the only way

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript integers are usually stored as a [Number value](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf):

> **4.3.19**
>   primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value

So the result of `parseInt` is a float where the value losslessly fits into the fraction part of the float (52 bits capacity). `parseInt` also doesn't parse it as two-complement notation.

If you want to force anything that you read into 32 bit, then the easiest would be two force it to be automatically converted to 32 bit by applying a binary operation. I would suggest:

```
parseInt("F7AA027F", 16) | 0
```

The binary OR (`|`) with 0 is essentially a no-op, but it converts any integer to 32 bit. This trick is often used in order to convert numbers to 32 bit in order to make calculations on it faster.

Also, this is portable.

Comment: Thank you Artom for the explanation.

Comment: this is the solution for Hex to INT32 - Big Endian (ABCD)! tyvm

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am trying to send accelerometer data from Arduino to Pi.

The raw data I am reading is that `[0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0xBA]`.

If you lack knowledge about the topic as me, use the [scadacore.com](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) website to find out find your data should correspond to. In my case it is **Float - Little Endian (DCBA)** which outputs: `-0.03126526`. Now we know what kind of a conversion that we need.

Then, check available functions based on the language. In my case, [Node.js buffer library offers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) `buf.readFloatLE([offset])` function which is the one I need.