# How to convert 4 byte Hex to floating-point number in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, type-conversion, hex

I have four bytes of Hex data, I am trying to convert it to floating-point number in Node.js.

i.e.

```
0x58 0x86 0x6B 0x42 --> 58.8812
0x76 0xD6 0xE3 0x42 --> 113.9189
0x91 0x2A 0xB4 0x41 --> 22.52078
```

I have tried to convert from different functions found on the internet, But unfortunately not getting the desired outcome.
On https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/ link I am getting proper value in "Float - Little Endian (DCBA)" cell by entering Hex string, But do not know how to do it in node js.
I think maybe I am searching the wrong thing or I have understood it wrong.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a string representation of your hex data (e.g. `'58866B42'` regarding your first example) do the following to convert it to a floating point number:

```
let myNumber = Buffer.from(hexString, 'hex').readFloatLE()
```

The `LE` in `readFloatLE` stands for ***L**ittle **E**ndian*.

Comment: Thank You.
I also found another solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239567/hex-string-to-int32-little-endian-dcba-format-javascript
Need to replace getInt32() to getFloat32() for my scenario.