# Javascript, convert array of numbers into double

Tags: javascript, arrays, byte

I need to convert an array of 8 bytes into a double.  This is my starting array:

```
[170, 85, 255, 63, 205, 171, 170, 85]
```

and it should convert to -9.591053231630682E-105.

Each element of the array can be from 0 to 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40970862/1447675) of [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)  and use [`DataView#setUint8`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setUint8) for the given bytes.

```js
var data =  [170, 85, 255, 63, 205, 171, 170, 85];

// Create a buffer
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
// Create a data view of it
var view = new DataView(buf);

// set bytes
data.forEach(function (b, i) {
    view.setUint8(i, b);
});

// Read the bits as a float
var num = view.getFloat64(0);
// Done
console.log(num);
```