# Convert uint8array to double in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, double, uint8array

I have an arraybuffer and I want to get double values.For example from [64, -124, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] I would get 641.5

Any ideas?

Comment: show us what you've tried and what's yoyr logic?

Comment: I have a function that returns the arraybuffer with the bytes from an audio file:                                                                                                        function getBuffer(resolve) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
        reader.onload = function () {
            var arrayBuffer = reader.result
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
            resolve(bytes);
        }
    }

Comment: Instead of bytes from 0 to 255 I need double values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could adapt the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40970862/1447675) of [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)  and use [`DataView#setUint8`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setUint8) for the given bytes.

```js
var data =  [64, -124, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

// Create a buffer
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
// Create a data view of it
var view = new DataView(buf);

// set bytes
data.forEach(function (b, i) {
    view.setUint8(i, b);
});

// Read the bits as a float/native 64-bit double
var num = view.getFloat64(0);
// Done
console.log(num);
```

For multiple numbers, you could take chunks of 8.

```js
function getFloat(array) {
    var view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(8));
    array.forEach(function (b, i) {
        view.setUint8(i, b);
    });
    return view.getFloat64(0);
}

var data =  [64, -124, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, -124, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    i = 0,
    result = [];

while (i < data.length) {
    result.push(getFloat(data.slice(i, i + 8)));
    i += 8;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: that looks good.But what if I have a longer array.For example:                 var data =  [64, -124, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,64, -124, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; Then the result would be: [641.5,641.5]

Comment: great!.Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from Nina Scholz I came up with a shorter:

```
function getFloat(data /* Uint8Array */) {
  return new DataView(data.buffer).getFloat64(0);
}
```

Or if you have a large array and know the offset:

```
function getFloat(data, offset = 0) {
  return new DataView(data.buffer, offset, 8).getFloat64(0);
}
```