# What the Hex is Going on with Milliseconds?

Tags: video, hex, metadata, webm, uint8array

I have the values `88` `40` `B0` `00`. They are is hex. I don't understand how, but they represent a number of nanoseconds. I need help with understand [this document](https://matroska.org/technical/elements.html#Duration) which outlines Matroska and WebM metadata encoding. I am relatively new to this, but I am using JavaScript to alter a file duration. What I am currently using works, but the goal is to know how to set a custom duration of the WebM video file. The document shows the following for the duration parameters:

- Element Name

  - Duration
- The level within an EBML tree

  - 2
- Element ID displayed as octets

  - 0x4489
- Mandatory

  - False
- May occur multiple times

  - False
- Contained in

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
- Available to use in WebM

  - True
- Description

  - Duration of the Segment in nanoseconds based on TimestampScale

I am using the default time stamp scale (`1000000`). My question is how to I get those hex values, and turn them into `hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds`. I simply am stumped :( `0x8840B000` doesn't help me.

Comment: Is it not 64 bits (8 hex values) instead of the 32 bits (4 hex values)...? I'm not well versed in MKV / WebM container but I've come across such info in the past, so just double-check that.

Comment: quicVO posted the same question on Video Production Stack Exchange: [What the Hex is Going on with Milliseconds?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/33138)

Comment: @Bavi_H, I did because I wanted to make sure that this question would get to the correct people. I was not sure which community was best, so I posted on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the Stack Overflow question about a [TimestampScale Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853363).

In this question, you are asking about a Duration Element.

The Duration Element you mentioned is made of

- Element ID `44 89`
- Element Data Size `88` (a 1-byte Variable-Size Integer indicating 8 bytes of Element Data follow)
- Element Data `40 B0 00 00 00 00 00 00` (a big-endian 64-bit float representation of decimal 4096)

In JavaScript, you can convert those 8 bytes to the corresponding float value they represent using code like the following (adapted from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56284628) to question [Convert uint8array to double in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153073))

```
let b = new Uint8Array([0x40, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]);
let f = (new DataView(b.buffer)).getFloat64();
```

When the TimestampScale value is the default (one million nanoseconds), then the Duration value is in milliseconds. In this case, the duration is 4096 milliseconds or 4.096 seconds.

If you want the duration in nanoseconds, multiply the Duration value by the TimestampScale value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How might I be able to turn a Float64 number into an array of hex values?

Comment: Also will it always be a Float64 rather than a Float32?

Comment: I know know that Float64 is of 8 values and Float32 is of 4 values. So 88-->Float64 variable, 84-->Float32 variable. Now that I know this, how might I be able to reverse a Float Number into a Uint8Array representing those values? I may ask a new question for this.

Comment: I made a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65877305/how-to-reverse-javascripts-dataview)

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help :)