# Explanation on Integer to Array

Tags: arrays, hex, webm, mkv, uint8array

### Please Help

I know that you are reading this, and I would appreciate a comment if do not have an answer because I feel that I am alone in trying to figure this out.

### How Does this Work?

I have thoroughly read [this document](https://matroska.org/technical/elements.html#TimestampScale). It mentions an element called TimestampScale. I have downloaded probably thirty WebM example files and seen that the values following the **HEX** { `0x2AD7B1` or `2A` `D7` `B1` or `['2A','D7','B1']` } or **NON-HEX integers** { `42` `215` `177` or `[42, 215, 177]` } are always the same: **HEX** { `0x830F4240` or `83` `0F` `42` `40` or `['83', '0F', '42', '40']` } or **NON-HEX integers** { `131` `15` `66` `64` or `[131,15,66,64]` }. The values all SHOULD be the default of `1000000` as stated in the Matroska Element Specification. So the question is... How does `0x830F4240` end up as `1000000`?

**Incase Above Was Too Sloppy For You or You Want More Explanation:**

```
The TimestampScale identifier is equal to 0x2AD7B1. This is in Hexadecimal formatting.

The ways I format it in HEX are:
    0x2AD7B1
    2A D7 B1
    ['2A','D7','B1']

The ways I format it in Integers are:
    42 215 177
    [42, 215, 177]



Its preceding values are taken from a Uint8Array: | 131, 15, 66, 64 |
after the Hexadecimal values are taken. This is NOT in Hexadecimal formatting.
The reason why is because that is the raw data and I want to be
as open with you as possible.

The ways I format it in HEX are:
    0x830F4240
    83 0F 42 40
    ['83','0F','42','40']

The ways I format it in Integers are:
    131 15 66 64
    [131,15,66,64]

So question is: how does | 131, 15, 66, 64 | or 0x830F4240 equal 1000000?
```

### How the all values are shown in HEX and Integers:

```
    Hex: 2A D7 B1 83 0F 42 40
    Integers: 42 215 177 131 15 66 64
```

### The Goal:

The goal is to figure out how to convert the values to make `1000000`, that way I can use this conversion on other elements in the Matroska Element Specification (like duration conversion).

Comment: +1, I am also very curious about this. I was trying to edit metadata in WebM/MKV format, but could figure out how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebM container format is a subset of the Matroska container format.

Matroska is based on [EBML (Extensible Binary Meta Language)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8794/?include_text=1).

An EBML Document is made of Elements.

An Element is made of an Element ID, an Element Data Size, and Element Data.

An Element Data Size is a Variable-Size Integer. (An Element ID is also a Variable-Size Integer.)

A Variable-Size Integer uses the kind of bit patterns shown below, where the leading bits indicate how many bytes are used and the `x` bits store the actual value.

- 1-byte: `1xxxxxxx`
- 2-byte: `01xxxxxx xxxxxxxx`
- 3-byte: `001xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx`
- 4-byte: `0001xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx`

and so on

The TimestampScale Element you mentioned is made of

- Element ID `2A D7 B1`
- Element Data Size `83` (a 1-byte Variable-Size Integer indicating 3 bytes of Element Data follow)
- Element Data `0F 42 40` (a big endian encoding of decimal 1000000)

Comment: How do you know that 83 refers to three bytes to follow?

Comment: Hex `83` is binary `10000011`. Because it is a Variable-Size Integer, the left-most `1` bit means that this Variable-Size Integer is one byte and that bit is not part of the value. The remaining bits `0000011` are the actual value, which is decimal 3.